# How to merge e-mail headers data into e-mail html message body in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, email-headers

I'm looking for a solution to put the e-mail's header like address, subject, date etc... Into the e-mail's message body. Like it works when forwarding an e-mail from any e-mail client.

Is there a good practice for it in PHP? I couldn't find it in the manual.
I'm using php with laravel.

```
$to = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message .= "<html><body>…Email Message 1…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$to = ($_POST['email']);
$subject = 'Subject';
$url = 'mydomain.caom'; 
$headers2 = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers2 .= "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>…Email Message 2…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers2);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL='.$url.'">';
}
```

Can I just concatenate the headers into the body?

Comment: Yes, you can.  That is the actual thing that other mail clients do when forwarding messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can!

You can do something like this

```php
$to = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';

$headers = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message_headers = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $headers);

$message = "<html><body>…Email Message 1…{$message_headers}</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The above will replace the new lines (`\r\n`) in `$headers` with the HTML `<br>` tag and the formatted headers will be added to the `$message` just before the closing `<body>` tag.

Also notice that I have removed the `.` from the `$message .= "...";` and replaced it with `$message = "...";`
You dont need the `.` unless you are appending the `$message` variable.

Comment: No problem :-) If you have more questions related to PHP I'd be happy to help out.